# Can't append nor concat two GeoDataFrames even though datas Share same CRS

Tags: pandas, data-science, gis, geopandas, analysis

Basically I was going through this tutorial where we did import data from OSM and throughout modifying the data, There was basically a command to add missing Highway speed limits to Unclassified Roads.

Here's the [`tutorial`](https://sustainability-gis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lessons/L2/spatial_network_analysis.html) and while recreating the GeoDataFrame dataset by combining the two frames using this command.

```
edges = edges_with_maxspeed.append(edges_without_maxspeed)
edges["maxspeed"].unique()
```

I got this:

```
ValueError: Cannot determine common CRS for concatenation inputs, got ['WGS 84']. Use `to_crs()` to transform geometries to the same CRS before merging.
```

Knowing as I mentioned above both datasets share the same CRS.

I tried this:

```
edges_with_maxspeed = edges_with_maxspeed.reset_index(drop=True)
edges_without_maxspeed = edges_without_maxspeed.reset_index(drop=True)
edges = edges.reset_index(drop=True)
edges = gpd.GeoDataFrame(pd.concat([edges_without_maxspeed, edges_with_maxspeed], ignore_index=True), crs=edges.crs)
```

and multiple other lines but couldn't figure out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of the dataframes doesn't have a crs. I'd first check which of the dataframes doesn't have a crs by doing:

```
print(edges_without_maxspeed.crs)
print(edges_with_maxspeed.crs)
```

Then, depending which one doesn't have a crs, you can set the crs of one to the other:

```
edges_without_maxspeed.crs = edges_with_maxspeed.crs
```

or...

```
edges_with_maxspeed.crs = edges_without_maxspeed.crs
```

Comment: I did solve the problem, It was Pandas 2.0.0 that caused geopandas to execute such an issue.

Comment: Installing Pandas 1.5.3 would solve the issue.